# PyGame: pygame.mouse.get_pos() tuple out of range?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm attempting to create Tic-Tac-Toe in PyGame. My issue is with the `mouse` module's function. Whenever I use `pygame.mouse.get_pos()` within `collidepoint()` it gives me a type error and says that my tuple's index is out of range. Anyone have any ideas?

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()
pygame.display.set_caption("Tic-Tac-Toe")
pygame.mouse.set_visible(True)

FPS = 60
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 500, 600
BORDER_THICKNESS = 10

WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))

# Declare font
GAME_FONT = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsans", 100)

# Colors
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)

def display_window(squares, marks, turn):
    WIN.fill(WHITE)
    starting_pos = WIDTH//3
    for l in range(2):

        # Draws the board
        vert = pygame.Rect((starting_pos - BORDER_THICKNESS//2, 0), (BORDER_THICKNESS, HEIGHT))
        hrzn = pygame.Rect((0, starting_pos - BORDER_THICKNESS//2), (WIDTH, BORDER_THICKNESS))
        starting_pos = starting_pos * 2 + BORDER_THICKNESS//2
        pygame.draw.rect(WIN, BLACK, vert)
        pygame.draw.rect(WIN, BLACK, hrzn)

    # Draws black background for text box
    more_border = pygame.Rect((0, WIDTH), (WIDTH, HEIGHT - WIDTH))
    pygame.draw.rect(WIN, BLACK, more_border)

    # Draws actual text box
    text_box = pygame.Rect((0 + BORDER_THICKNESS, WIDTH + BORDER_THICKNESS), (WIDTH-BORDER_THICKNESS*2, HEIGHT - WIDTH))
    pygame.draw.rect(WIN, WHITE, text_box)

    # Display game squares
    for s in squares:
        pygame.draw.rect(WIN, GREEN, s)

    # Draws the x's and o's
    for m in marks:
        pass    # Still working on displaying the marks
    pygame.display.update()

# Use the mouse module functions in order to retrieve location where the
# mouse pointer is at and see if it collides with a given square.
def mouse_movement(squares, mouse_presses, marks, turn):
    for s in squares:
        if s.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()) and mouse_presses[pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN]:
            if turn % 2 == 1:
                marks[squares.index(s)] = 'X'
            elif turn % 2 == 0:
                marks[squares.index(s)] = 'O'
            else:
                raise TypeError("Neither condition is being met.")
            
    
def main():
    turn = 1
    x, y = 0, 0
    squares = []
    for c in range(3):
        for r in range(3):
            squares.append(pygame.Rect((x, y), (WIDTH//3 -BORDER_THICKNESS//2, WIDTH//3 - BORDER_THICKNESS//2)))
            x += WIDTH//3 - BORDER_THICKNESS//2 + BORDER_THICKNESS
        x = 0
        y += WIDTH//3 - BORDER_THICKNESS//2 + BORDER_THICKNESS
    
    marks = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']

    game_going = True
    while game_going:
        clock.tick(FPS)

        for event in pygame.event.get():

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                game_going = False
                pygame.quit()

        print(pygame.mouse.get_pos())    
        mouse_presses = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
        marks = mouse_movement(squares, mouse_presses, marks, turn)
        display_window(squares, marks, turn)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I searched the PyGame website to make sure that `pygame.mouse.get_pos()` returns a tuple and it does. I'm not quite sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

You get the out of range exception because of `mouse_presses[pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN]`.

[`pygame.mouse.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html#pygame.mouse.get_pressed) returns a list of Boolean values ​​that represent the state (`True` or `False`) of all mouse buttons. The state of a button is `True` as long as a button is held down. When multiple buttons are pressed, multiple items in the list are `True`. The 1st, 2nd and 3rd elements in the list represent the left, middle and right mouse buttons.

If you want to test if the left mouse button is pressed it is:

```py
if mouse_presses[0]:
```

If you want to test if any button is pressed it is:

```py
if any(mouse_presses):
```

However, this is not how the `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` event works. The `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` event occurs once when you click the mouse button and the `MOUSEBUTTONUP` event occurs once when the mouse button is released. The [`pygame.event.Event()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.Event) object has two attributes that provide information about the mouse event. `pos` is a tuple that stores the position that was clicked. `button` stores the button that was clicked. Each mouse button is associated a value. For instance the value of the attributes is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 for the left mouse button, middle mouse button, right mouse button, mouse wheel up respectively mouse wheel down. When multiple keys are pressed, multiple mouse button events occur. Further explanations can be found in the documentation of the module [`pygame.event`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html).

e.g.:

```py
game_going = True
while game_going:
    # [...]

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            game_going = False
                
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 1: # left button
                print(event.pos)  # mouse position
                # [...]
```